# limit problem - can't get rid of $0$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\arcsin x - \arctan x}{e^x-\cos x -x^2 -x}$$

I tried to use known limit in denominator to get:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\arcsin}{x} - \frac{\arctan x}{x}}{x( \frac{e^x-1}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} -1 -\frac{1}{x})}$$

But I still get $1-1=0$ in numerator. I also tried to use L'Hôpital rule, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use L‘hospital multiple times:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\arcsin x - \arctan x}{e^x-\cos x -x^2 -x}
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - \frac{1}{x^2+1}}{e^x+\sin x -2x-1} 
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^3}} + \frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}}{e^x+\cos x -2}
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^5}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2)^3}} - \frac{8x^2}{(x^2+1)^3} \frac{2}{(x^2+1)^2}}{e^x-\sin x}
 = \frac{3}{1} =3.
$$

**Edit:** I edited my pot. My original answer was just wrong.

Comment: The answer is not $0$ by the way.  According to Wolfram, we have $3$.  Also, don't forget the derivative of $x$.

Comment: Correct. My original answer had a huge error, I edited my post. :)

Comment: yes 3 is the solution in the book. I kind of hoped I wouldn't have to use L'Hospital rule multiple times, but as other answers only suggest using Taylor series, I guess I don't have any other choice, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: If you know that $e^x = 1+x+{x^2\over2}+{x^3\over6}+\dots$ and $\cos x=1-{x^2\over2}+{x^4\over24}-\dots$, you can see that the denominator is ${x^3\over6}+\dots$, so the limit reduces to

$$6\lim_{x\to0}{\arcsin x-\arctan x\over x^3}$$

Comment: Very nice way to evaluate the limit.  Way better than L'Hôpital Rule for this type of problem.

Comment: @NasuSama. For sure, it is much better and based on the same principles (almost). Do the same for the numerator and conclude.

Comment: Well, it's sort of L'Hôpital in disguise.

Comment: Great answer. A possible problem is that limits are usually taught before Taylor series.

Comment: where does $e^x = 1+x+{x^2\over2}+{x^3\over6}+\dots$ come from? Is it related to Taylor series as the comment by Leo Azevedo imply? Because I don't know this way of solving problems, but it does looks neat and I hope I will learn it soon.

Comment: @cryogenic, yes, it's the Taylor series, as laid out more fully in Sami Ben Romdhane's answer.  You have something to look forward to!

Comment: thank you for your answer, I hope you understand why I didn't accept it as an answer even though it is very nice. :)

Answer (score 6):

Using the Taylor series 
$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(0)+o(x^3)$$
for $f$ is $\arcsin$ and $\arctan$ we find
$$\arcsin x=x+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$$
and 
$$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)$$
and we have
$$e^x-\cos x-x^2-x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}-1+\frac{x^2}{2}-x^2-x+o(x^3)=\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$$
hence
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\arcsin x - \arctan x}{e^x-\cos x -x^2 -x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)}{\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}=3$$

Comment: Nicely using the Taylor series. +1